# "IllegalStateException: state should be: open" when using mapPartitions with Mongo connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

## The setup

I have a simple Spark application that uses `mapPartitions` to transform an RDD. As part of this transformation, I retrieve some necessary data from a Mongo database. The connection from the Spark worker to the Mongo database is managed using the MongoDB Connector for Spark (https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/).

I'm using `mapPartitions` instead of the simpler `map` because there is some relatively expensive setup that is only required once for all elements in a partition. If I were to use `map` instead, this setup would have to be repeated for every element individually.

## The problem

When one of the partitions in the source RDD becomes large enough, the transformation fails with the message

```
IllegalStateException: state should be: open
```

or, occasionally, with

```
IllegalStateException: The pool is closed
```

## The code

Below is the code of a simple Scala application with which I can reproduce the issue:

```
package my.package

import com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.bson.Document

object MySparkApplication {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
            .appName("MySparkApplication")
            .master(???) // The Spark master URL
            .config("spark.jars", ???) // The path at which the application's fat JAR is located.
            .config("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
            .config("spark.mongodb.keep_alive_ms", "86400000")
            .getOrCreate()

        val mongoConnector: MongoConnector = MongoConnector(Map(
            "uri" -> ??? // The MongoDB URI.
            , "spark.mongodb.keep_alive_ms" -> "86400000"
            , "keep_alive_ms" -> "86400000"
        ))

        val localDocumentIds: Seq[Long] = Seq.range(1L, 100L)
        val documentIdsRdd: RDD[Long] = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(localDocumentIds)

        val result: RDD[Document] = documentIdsRdd.mapPartitions { documentIdsIterator =>
            mongoConnector.withMongoClientDo { mongoClient =>
                val collection = mongoClient.getDatabase("databaseName").getCollection("collectionName")
                // Some expensive query that should only be performed once for every partition.
                collection.find(new Document("_id", 99999L)).first()

                documentIdsIterator.map { documentId =>
                    // An expensive operation that does not interact with the Mongo database.
                    Thread.sleep(1000)
                    collection.find(new Document("_id", documentId)).first()
                }
            }
        }

        val resultLocal = result.collect()
    }
}
```

## The stack trace

Below is the stack trace returned by Spark when I run the application above:

```
Driver stacktrace:
    [...]
    at my.package.MySparkApplication.main(MySparkApplication.scala:41)
    at my.package.MySparkApplication.main(MySparkApplication.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open
    at com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.isTrue(Assertions.java:70)
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:152)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.getConnectedClusterDescription(Mongo.java:885)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.createClientSession(Mongo.java:877)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$3.getClientSession(Mongo.java:866)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$3.execute(Mongo.java:823)
    at com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl.first(FindIterableImpl.java:193)
    at my.package.MySparkApplication$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(MySparkApplication.scala:36)
    at my.package.MySparkApplication$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(MySparkApplication.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

## The research I have done

I have found several people asking about this issue, and it seems that in all of their cases, the problem turned out to be them using  the Mongo client after it had been closed. As far as I can tell, this is not happening in my application - opening and closing the connection should be handled by the Mongo-Spark connector, and I would expect the client to only be closed after the function passed to `mongoConnector.withMongoClientDo` returns.

I did manage to discover that the issue does not arise for the very first element in the RDD. It seems instead that a number of elements are being processed successfully, and that the failure only occurs once the process has taken a certain amount of time. This amount of time seems to be on the order of 5 to 15 seconds.

The above leads me to believe that something is automatically closing the client once it has been active for a certain amount of time, *even though it is still being used*.

As you can tell by my code, I have discovered the fact that the Mongo-Spark connector exposes a configuration `spark.mongodb.keep_alive_ms` that, according to the connector documentation, controls "The length of time to keep a MongoClient available for sharing". Its default value is 5 seconds, so this seemed like a useful thing to try. In the application above, I attempt to set it to an entire day in three different ways, with zero effect. The documentation does state that this specific property "can only be configured via a System Property". I think that this is what I'm doing (by setting the property when initialising the Spark session and/or Mongo connector), but I'm not entirely sure. It seems to be impossible to verify the setting once the Mongo connector has been initialised.

One other StackOverflow question mentions that I should try setting the `maxConnectionIdleTime` option in the `MongoClientOptions`, but as far as I can tell it is not possible to set these options through the connector.

As a sanity check, I tried replacing the use of `mapPartitions` with a functionally equivalent use of `map`. The issue disappeared, which is probably because the connection to the Mongo database is re-initialised for each individual element of the RDD. However, as mentioned above, this approach would have significantly worse performance because I would end up repeating expensive setup work for every element in the RDD.

Out of curiosity I also tried replacing the call to `mapPartitions` with a call to `foreachPartition`, also replacing the call to `documentIdsIterator.map` with `documentIdsIterator.foreach`. The issue also disappeared in this case. I have no idea why this would be, but because I need to transform my RDD, this is also not an acceptable approach.

## The kind of answer I am looking for

- "You actually *are* closing the client prematurely, and here's where: [...]"
- "This is a known issue in the Mongo-Spark connector, and here's a link to their issue tracker: [...]"
- "You are setting the `spark.mongodb.keep_alive_ms` property incorrectly, this is how you should do it: [...]"
- "It is possible to verify the value of `spark.mongodb.keep_alive_ms` on your Mongo connector, and here's how: [...]"
- "It is possible to set `MongoClientOptions` such as `maxConnectionIdleTime` through the Mongo connector, and here's how: [...]"

## Edit

Further investigation has yielded the following insight:
The phrase 'System property' used in the connector's documentation refers to a Java system property, set using `System.setProperty("spark.mongodb.keep_alive_ms", desiredValue)` or the command line option `-Dspark.mongodb.keep_alive_ms=desiredValue`. This value is then read by the `MongoConnector` singleton object, and passed to the `MongoClientCache`. However, neither of the approaches for setting this property actually works:

- Calling `System.setProperty()` from the driver program sets the value only in the JVM for the Spark driver program, while the value is needed in the Spark worker's JVM.
- Calling `System.setProperty()` from the worker program sets the value only after it is read by `MongoConnector`.
- Passing the command line option `-Dspark.mongodb.keep_alive_ms` to the Spark option `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` again only sets the value in the driver's JVM.
- Passing the command line option to the Spark option `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` results in an error message from Spark:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: spark.executor.extraJavaOptions is not allowed to set Spark options (was '-Dspark.mongodb.keep_alive_ms=desiredValue'). Set them directly on a SparkConf or in a properties file when using ./bin/spark-submit.
```

The Spark code that throws this error is located in `org.apache.spark.SparkConf#validateSettings`, where it checks for any worker option value that contains the string `-Dspark`.

This seems like an oversight in the design of the Mongo connector; either the property should be set through the Spark session (as I originally expected it to be), or it should be renamed to something that doesn't start with `spark`. I added this information to the JIRA ticket mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I cross-posted this question to the MongoDB user group mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/IKUHz1Ax4JA/A-7yMlg0CwAJ

Comment: A ticket has been created for this issue in the issue tracker for the connector: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SPARK-243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core issue is that the `MongoConnector` uses a cache for MongoClients and follows the loan pattern for managing that cache. Once all loaned MongoClients are returned and the `keep_alive_ms` time has passed the `MongoClient` will be closed and removed from the cache.

Due to the nature of how RDD's are implemented (they follow Scala's lazy collection semantics) the following code: `documentIdsIterator.map { documentId => ... }` is only processed *once* the RDD is actioned.  By that time the loaned `MongoClient` has already been returned back to the cache and after the `keep_alive_ms` the `MongoClient` will be closed.  This results in a `state should be open` exception on the client.

How to solve?

1. You could once [SPARK-246](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SPARK-246) is fixed set the `keep_alive_ms` to be high enough so that the `MongoClient` is not closed during the processing of the RDD.  However, that still breaks the contract of the loan pattern that the `MongoConnector` uses - so should be avoided.
2. Reuse the `MongoConnector` to get the client as needed.  This way the cache can still be used, should a client be available, but should a client timeout for any reason then a new one will be automatically created:

```
documentIdsRdd.mapPartitions { documentIdsIterator =>
   mongoConnector.withMongoClientDo { mongoClient =>
      // Do some expensive operation
      ...

      // Return the lazy collection
      documentIdsIterator.map { documentId => 
         // Loan the mongoClient
         mongoConnector.withMongoClientDo { mongoClient => ... }
      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Connection objects are in general tightly bound to the context, in which they where initialized. You cannot simply serialize such objects and pass them around. Instead you these should be initialized in-place, in the mapPartitions:

```
val result: RDD[Document] = documentIdsRdd.mapPartitions { documentIdsIterator =>
  val mongoConnector: MongoConnector = MongoConnector(Map(
    "uri" -> ??? // The MongoDB URI.
    , "spark.mongodb.keep_alive_ms" -> "86400000"
    , "keep_alive_ms" -> "86400000"
  ))
  mongoConnector.withMongoClientDo { mongoClient =>
   ...
 }
}
```

Comment: Like I said in the original question, the issue only appears once the initial RDD is large enough. If your claim were true, my code would never work. As far as I am aware, the Mongo-Spark connector is actually *intended* to be serialised, and then used to create a Mongo client worker-side.

Comment: Just to be sure, I tried this approach (initialising the connector on the worker) and it still results in the same error.